# Using JQuery and Ajax to test status of links

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm writing a script which tests if any links within a particular `div` 404. 
**Outline**:

1. Iterate through links with jquery .each()
2. Test status of link with ajax
3. Add either a "linkSuccess" or "linkFail" class to the link.

The function is successfully testing the URLs but I can't seem to apply a class to the link. I'm guessing I have a scope problem.

**Code**

```
function testLinks() { 
$('.editor a').each(function(i)  {
    var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: thisUrl, 
        type: 'get',
        method: 'get',
        error: function() {
            $(this).addClass('linkFail');
        },
        success: function() { 
            $(this).addClass('linkSuccess');
        }
    }); 

});
```

}

How do I get the ajax portion of the function to recognize the link element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the ajax call $(this) is not $j('.editor a') anymore
try:

```
function testLinks() { 
$('.editor a').each(function(i)  {
    var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href');

    var element = $(this); 

    $.ajax({
        url: thisUrl, 
        type: 'get',
        method: 'get',
        error: function() {
            element.addClass('linkFail');
        },
        success: function() { 
            element.addClass('linkSuccess');
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I set something up _almost_ exactly like this but must have misplaced something.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because `$(this)` in the success callback of the ajax call is no longer the `a` element grabbed by the selector in the first step.  Try copying `$(this)` to a local variable before firing off the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is referring to the ajax element.  I think `$(this).parent().addClass('linkFail')` should work.

http://api.jquery.com/parent/